# What do I need to consider for a justice system for powered people by powered people?

Tags: super-powers, law, alternate-earth, law-enforcement

In one of my stories, there are people with powers. Inherited from parent to child or through accident and experimentation. There's the main government like ours, and a para-military agency organisation that is involved with dealing with unusual events, objects and people, such as gifted people.

( A bit of background is this, Gifted people aren't yet common but they do happen so this agency deals with them by indexes any and all gifted people once found and released with monitoring about their use of abilities. Including the use in self-defence. The normal government doesn't really know or deal with this themselves due to the reliance on the Agency until there's a public exposure problem in the event of a crime or accident.

Gifted people aren't common enough that they don't have a method of justice in the normal human legal system when facing a public trial and being gifted can easily put the person at a disadvantage with human prejudice of being able to do something a human cannot and risks that come with abilities. More often than not, they're sent to the agency for imprisonment since that 'assures' the human government the threat is appropriately dealt with. Again, more background information on background issues. )

**However**, there's a community of gifted people that do live away from humans. Which is what I'm curious in exploring more than the human vs gifted.

Now, what I'm looking for is trying to create a justice system that's been developed by powered people for powered people. A majority of the community are isolated in culture but there are the ones that join this community, like my MC. But as this is a different culture, ways of the justice system would have differences to our justice system.

But I remain uncertain on what I'd need to consider in terms of building on in terms of the laws and codes of justice. Powers are good, yet there would still be things to be considered;

- **Moral implications and ethics** in use of abilities, such as transferring the mind of a person with a terminal illness into the body of another that is otherwise brain-dead. Grey areas of abilities can be hard to fit into a standard code of systems.
- **Damage** of the property and/or people if the use of power is uncontrolled or in a fight, etc,
- **Conduct** of those with potentially intrusive abilities (mind-reading, x-ray vision, etc)

I know that there'd no doubt been a long list of powers that'd have a chapter in the system to maintain the community.

**What would I need to consider with what I've got so far to build a functional justice system?** or Would I just expand on what I've got into finer details?

Comment: as far as i read, i dont found what this gifted people ability is, are all of them have same super power ability? and what kind?

Comment: @LiJun No, all of the people have unique and variable abilities like Mutants. some share similar gifts to each other of course but have different styles. No two painters have the same result.

Comment: Which powers they have are vital.  For instance, if some had mental powers, it would be necessary to have prisons where they could be prevented from tormenting the guards or people outside the prison.  If they have teleportation, they would need walls impervious to it.

Comment: Why would there be a difference, especially if there are so few that they can't force the issue? Why would the victims (literally or the sufferers of collateral damage) not have the right to sit as peers? You're asking how to invent a legal system that lets the wealthy only be judged by the wealthy or men to only be judged by men. Such a legal system would be intrinsically unbalanced and would eventually lead to violence - and, therefore, a change in the legal system. It might be possible to create something like a military system vs. civilian - but even that crosses over.

Comment: @JBH Probably because in this case the aristocracy have laser eyes and can kill anyone who points out the violence inherent in the system. They aren't normal people who have soft power through connections and access to resources. The aristocracy (powereds) being held to a different standard from the commoners (normals) has been a codified part of a lot of societal legal structures over the millenia.

Comment: so this community is all gifted right? i guess the judge probably need to be the one with mind reading/liar detector, psychic and such, and prison probably will be specially made for each individual criminals to counter their ability and maybe more simpler if theres a gifted ppl with that kind of power or a power that can nullified others gifter powers. at least seems like they cant run away from that community. but the chance for them has this convenient ability since ancient times for this specific job maybe questionable, though you mention parent inheritance....

Comment: @LiJun Yes, each generation inherit genetic for powers that can remain dorman until artificial activation or puberty, though, again the variance of the powers is reflected on the individual. That said, there might be a pattern to gifts resurfacing in a newly gifted person.

Comment: @user2352714 humanity is remarkably adept at killing creatures that represent a larger threat than other humans. If that situation actually existed, powered people would be extinct fairly quickly. Who cares about laser eyes when snipers can kill at over a mile  (I get it that your scenario doesn't have snipers... but you get my point, right? Think "mastadons")? Like I said, what would be the difference?

Comment: @JBH The community itself is isolated away from humans for the sake of their protection. Generations would be born out of human society. But there are some born into human society that comes into their powers. human vs human, human vs gifted and gifted vs gifted in the justice systems are no doubt going to be radically different with each other based on culture, prejudice and what they can do and how they perceive human and gifted individuals. A human in a gifted-justice situation would be at a disadvantage just as a gifted in a human-jutice system.

Comment: @SKKennell so what you're telling me is that the community is homogeneous with no particular distinction in capabilities (assuming the consequence of all power balances out). So... I'm still voting there would be no difference. Choose an existing justice system to duplicate. Either that or there isn't enough information for an answer. Why do you think there would be a difference? "Powers" isn't enough. Society has smarter & dummer people, stronger & weaker, faster & slower. Existing systems work because few individuals are remarkably outside the statistical norm.

Comment: @JBH There are portions of gifted with abilities dormant for a few generations, that's how they end up in the human population to start with. Those generations are cultured differently and may hold different responses to crimes and issues. If they're relocated to the gifted community, I'd expect there to be a cultural difference to be shown, just like how some of our countries have differences in their justice system in comparison.

Comment: @JBH In most of these scenarios the mastodons aren't organized and politically savvy as well. Mastodons can't manipulate people with words or form armies of their own. This is a human vs human conflict, not human versus non-sapient species. You're basically asking "well why didn't the peasants all just get sniper rifles and shoot the people in power"? Especially as this divide has been going on for generations giving the supers ways to monopolize access to the best military technology.

Comment: In the US, it would require a constitutional amendment to have a separate justice system. And it wouldn't be necessary. And if there were a hidden society of gifted that was a perceived threat to the world, enough nukes should be able to destroy it. It wouldn't need to be a real threat, just look like one to paranoid politicians.

Answer (score 9):

**No one super who is drastically more powerful than anyone else**

The way human society tends to "work" is that people are mostly safe because physically humans beings are more or less equal within a margin of error. Yes, some people are stronger than others, but in a straight-up fight stripped of followers and political power even the most brutal warlord is still human. Even the strongest person will still likely lose against a gang formed by the second, third, and fourth strongest. Even if you bring up differences in strength between men and women, those differences are in the sense of "on average". Women can still kill men if they have the element of surprise, have weapons, are more skilled fighters, are just bigger, etc.

What this means is that every individual in society has to be on their best behavior, because if they aren't the rest of society will gang up on them and take them down if they start negatively impacting the group. Introduce superpowers, however, and now you have a system where one person (like some super-psychic or flying brick) can set themselves up as leader through brute force and nobody can do anything about it. Reminds me of the saying in Greek myth where Zeus tells the other Olympians "I'm in charge because I'm the strongest, even if the rest of you all teamed up on me at once you could not bring me down" [paraphrased].

Human legal systems are mostly based on the concept of isonomy "all individuals are essentially equal [by which I mean talents like intellect or physical stature are negligable], and therefore shall be treated as equal under the law". Except now you have a situtation where this is blatantly not true. Not only do you have a situation where people are *not* equal under the law (normals versus supers), but you have individuals that even if you wanted to you cannot force to comply. Who is going to successfully arrest Superman if he breaks the law? So with that, you devolve into a society of barbarism with just one rule: don't make the super-gods mad. Society becomes intrisically based around what you and what you can do rather than who you are when you introduce variable superpowers (and people without) into the mix.

Incidentally, this is a lot of the reason why Superman makes a lot of people antsy despite being a big blue boyscout (which we'll hereafter call the "Lex Luthor argument"). Superman technically doesn't need humanity in any direct way. He doesn't rely on other people for food, or shelter, or resources. When he needs to pay taxes on the Fortress of Solitude he just crushes coal into diamonds. An army of normals couldn't stop him. An army of superheroes debatably couldn't stop him, unless you were very careful who you picked (i.e., other flying bricks) or very sneaky (read: Kryptonite). Humanity has no way to put a check on his power. There is nothing to stop him from setting himself up as a god-king through physical force beyond his own conscience. And most human beings aren't as virtuous as Superman (and there's the whole, "Clark Kent likes being normal" aspect, but that's neither here nor there).

Comment: There is no one powerset that will always make you incontestable.  Yes, Superman could floor stomp most supers, but Professor X could just make him eat a nice hunk of Kryptonite and be done with it.  Then if Professor X tried to control the world, Magneto could just walk up and choke him to death with his bare hands if he so chooses.  Then when Magneto tries to rule the world, the Flash could take him out before he has time to react, etc, etc... This means it would still take the cooperation of many supers to dominate the world,

Comment: ...and for this, they'd still need a system of law because oligarchies don't function without them.  The closest outcome to this I can really foresee is a system of nobility where Superman might rule the world, but the most powerful supers being his barons, which each have less powerful supers serving under them, who have less powerful supers under them, each tier having a different set or rights and privileges until you get down to the normies who are basically just serfs. Feudalism already assumes isonomy is false; so, it should work well for this.

Comment: @Nosajimiki The only reason Superman even has Kryptonite is to make Superman more relatable and to give him weaknesses so he isn't a Mary Sue and can have decent story arcs. There is no guarantee your uber-flying bricks would have such a crippling Achilles heel unless the author decides to throw one in for the sake of the story. A better comparison might be *Watchmen*, where Dr. Manhattan could basically do whatever he wanted as long as he wasn't stupid about it and the only thing stopping him was his own ennui and nihlism.

Comment: I think you make a good point about situations where there is only 1 superhuman. In Watchmen, Dr. Manhattan was the only person with extraordinary abilities.  Everyone else were just Batman tier humans; so, there was no pool of superpowers to pick from to oppose him with.  But, the OP is asking about an entire society of people with diverse super powers. In this case, it seem probable that there are always going to be a few supers who have the right powers to trump you regardless of what you bring to the table.

Answer (score 5):

### Treat Super Powers Like Gun Ownership

The US legal system already pretty much addresses this problem in the form of "aggravated" and "reckless endangerment" crimes.

To dissuade the use of deadly weapons, the sentencing for any crime becomes more severe anywhere a weapon is involved in the execution of the crime, even if it is not used to harm anyone.  If you rob a store with your bare hands, it is robbery, but if you use a gun to do it, it is aggravated robbery. Using super powers to rob a store creates the same sort of unfair, traumatizing, and increasingly dangerous sort of power dynamic as a gun; so, when a super does use their powers in a crime, the punishment is elevated which would hopefully be enough to convince at least some would be criminal supers to commit crimes using their mundane abilities as much as possible.

On the same token, carrying a gun is not illegal, getting into a fight with a gun on your person is not an aggravated crime, shooting a gun in a safe environment not illegal, and being a super is not illegal.  Supers are allowed have powers and use them in ways that common sense would tell you are safe and legal, but using your powers recklessly (like firing a gun blindly into the air) is a crime unto itself. This leaves the subject of using one's powers somewhere along the vein of, if you are not sure it is safe, you can get in trouble for it.

There may also be certain zero tolerance zones, like gun free zones, where using powers is entirely forbidden.

The advantage of treating all powers like gun ownership is that you don't criminalize anyone for having one power or another, you only criminalize its misuse.  Using mind control to steal a car is still grand theft auto, but now it is aggravated grand theft auto.  Using super strength to crush a person's skull is still murder, but now it's aggravated murder.  Creating a situation that blinds drivers is reckless endangerment whether you do it by throwing eggs at their windshields or by conjuring up a smoke screen. The definition of crimes are all about what you are doing instead of what powers you are using to do it; so, you can keep your code of laws relatively fair and simple.

As a bonus, this approach to super power law would be pretty consistent with normal people law such that it would work even outside of their own special culture.

*Side note: in some countries, people with unordinary physical abilities like formal martial arts training can be prosecuted for aggravated assault even without a weapon.  In a since, these jurisdictions already handle "super powers" this way.*

### Addressing your specific concerns

**Moral implications:** Legal systems are about ethics, not morality.  The general rule of law is that that which is not illegal is legal until it is not, and any moral implications beyond that is not for the courts to decide.  Transferring the mind of a person with a terminal illness into the body of another that is otherwise brain-dead is perfectly legal as long as you can prove you are not killing either person in the process under the current definitions of murder.  If it does kill one of the people, then you would need to petition legislatures to define this action as an exception to the law.  If it's not illegal, but congress sees it as a "form of murder" then it could be made illegal.

Also, most US states also use precedent in the evaluation of the law to stand in for congressional decisions until the law can be refined. So, the first time someone decides to press charges for something ambiguous like this, it could be decided very quickly if it is considered murder or not by the first court case that evaluates it.  Then everyone knows if that strange thing is or is not murder moving forward.

**Excessive Damage to Property:** Damage to property laws should suffice.  The plaintiff brings you to court, damages are assessed, and you are required to pay restitution, and if the damages exceed a certain amount or your ability to repay them, then there can be felony charges that stack which could result in jail time.

**Conduct of those with potentially intrusive abilities:** Laws concerning fraud and coercion are generally left intentionally vague because people are so creative when it comes to finding new ways to do them.  Fraud is defined as any intentional deception or misrepresentation used to benefit yourself or someone else, and coercion covers any use of threats, commands, and any use of force. So, if you can implant false memories or impulses directly into someone's mind, that is clearly Fraud.  If you tell a person to jump off a bridge and they do, that is coercion. So, without modifying the law at all, most of the more insidious intrusive abilities are already covered.

As for simple mind reading, there are no laws to prevent it, but there are many laws to prevent the use of said knowledge.  You can steal someone's PPI sure, but using it to take their money is theft, using it to get into their digital accounts is hacking, and using it create accounts in their names is identity theft, using it to ruin a person's reputation is defamation, using it to manipulate them is blackmail, so on and so forth.

If you really want to crack down on psychic intrusion, you could expand [CFAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act) law to cover the misuse of psychic abilities according to the same criteria that we evaluate hacking, since psychic intrusion and hacking are so similar in nature.

Comment: Honestly, this is the most realistic response. We don't like change and writing a whole new batch of laws is a lot of effort for something we can just shoehorn into our existing ones. (especially if this leaves interesting legal loopholes to be exploited in the story once before being changed as a result of a court case)

Answer (score 2):

### Build up from Tyranny

There are superhumans among us now. A tiny number of people, on paper, own (directly or indirectly) most everything. These could split into empires and armies clashing, suppressing, and ruling by force. Much like an overpowered superhero might.

But they don't. Why? These super humans are satisfied that concerns of great urgency to them are infrequent and can be worked out through a system. They are satisfied with roles as influencers, trend setters, deal makers, and moon shot-ers. They are satisfied that, at the moment, the benefits of arming and going to war with the world do not justify the expense to stability, mobility, safety, and peace of mind.

Similarly, your superhuman justice system would need to satisfy the people with the greatest strength that their needs can be cared for by that justice system. It means that sometimes justice might not be served, or sometimes their will be crisis between principles and the wants of one of these most mighty superhumans. But, as long as they are satisfied that what they care about is being taken care of expeditiously, it might be possible to convince them to hang up the cape and play chess, or make films, or something like that.

### Build up also from Anarchy

The public consists of very large numbers. To provide for their needs is impossible, hence the adage "you can't please all of the people all of the time".

However, a public of normal or superhumans can be satisfied with a justice system that lets them know what to expect. In this case, the decisions made should (most of the time) be easily predictable by experts on the topic. It should be easy enough that the public can deal with a lot of justice requests on their own.

Examples: a written legal code (like the Lextalionis) with descriptions of requirements and penalties for non-compliance, a well-understood system of arbitrating disputes : who makes the decisions, how disputes are presented, timeliness; a written constitution that in broad strokes outlines principles of government; a mechanism for evolving the rules and procedures (a law- or rule- making body).

The public needs to trust that most of the time, "the process" delivers results they will be happy with. If they can rest assured the system will take care of them, the public will defend it.

### Some Suggestions

**Define person** : everyone struggles with this one. From the ${3 \over 5}^{ths}$ compromise in the constitution, to tribalism, to the elderly, to criminals, the insane, the young, the very young, those on life-saving equipment, and those without "gifts". Who is entitled to full protection of "the system"? Who gets less than full protection? Who gets nothing?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should consider is the possibility of super powers adjusting an individual's personality, and at the extreme, power-induced-psychosis or sapient/sentient powers. Let me outline a couple example cases:

- An individual develops some sort of changer-power which lets them transform into a bear or whatever. Unfortunately, when they're in bear-form, they can't keep "control" and often act far more violently than they would in human form. Even worse, the longer the individual goes without transforming, the more the "urge" to transform grows. Now, say this individual kills someone while in bear form. Are they at fault? Can they plead mental illness?
- An individual develops some sort of mover/shaker power which enables them to warp space into pocket dimensions and teleport. Unfortunately, with this power comes an extreme case of kleptomania. The individual gets physically ill if they do not regularly steal things to appease their power, and this can't be "cheesed": the individual needs to actually believe that they've stolen something to appease the power. How do you deal with this? What if it can be conclusively proven that the individual's kleptomania disappears inside a power-nullification zone?
- An individual develops an exotic "demon summoning" power and gains the ability to summon temporary "demons" which they can use to fight or whatever. Unfortunately, as a byproduct of his power, infernal creatures whisper in their head all the time and drive them to commit crimes or other nefarious deeds. Is the individual at fault? Can the demons be prosecuted in a court?
- An individual develops an extreme changer power which essentially transforms them into a ghost. While in ghost form, they can't interact with the world, eat, sleep, or even breathe. The only way to survive is if they're actively possessing someone--otherwise they suffocate if they can't hold their breath. Unfortunately, possession is very invasive and the ghost-individual instantly has full control of the victim along with instantaneous access to all their knowledge. How would a court handle something like this? Prohibiting the individual from possessing people would kill them, but at the same time, it would be very hard to fight a willing possessee without hopping through a couple unwilling bodies beforehand. Similar problems rise up with people who develop vampire-esque powers requiring them to drink blood, eat dreams, or be a cannibal to survive.

Answer (score 1):

**Themis.**

There is a super whose power is to be the justice system.  She is extremely old but not aged in appearance.  She may be immortal.  She has a depth of understanding beyond that of normal people and supers both and her gift is the gift of fairness.  And she is blind.

Judicial matters involving supers (and sometimes those not) are brought before Justice.

---

A problem with this system is that it has all the proverbial eggs in one basket.  What if Justice were not able to carry out her duties?  What if she were kidnapped and held for ransom?  And how would this entity Justice comport herself in such a situation?